# Splunk produces a table with only one row

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I am using a splunk dashboard to parse a key-value log file into a table.

This is the search i am using :

```
...
<row>
    <panel>
      <title>Regdata Recon</title>
      <table>
        <search>
          <query>REGDATA-RECON reconStartTime
          | eval reconStartTime1=strptime('reconStartTime', "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.%Q")    <-- this is the format from the log
          | eval reconEndTime1=strptime('reconEndTime', "%Y-%m-%dT%H-%M-%S.%Q")
          | eval reconStart=strftime('reconStartTime1', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
          | eval reconEnd=strftime('reconEndTime1', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
          | fields - reconStartTime1 - reconEndTime1
          | table environment,reconStart,reconEnd,Duration,result 
          | sort reconStart</query>
          <earliest>$timeRange.earliest$</earliest>
          <latest>$timeRange.latest$</latest>
          <sampleRatio>1</sampleRatio>
        </search>
        ...
      </table>
    </panel>
</row>
```

However, while there are many lines in the log file which satisfy this search, my dashboard gives me a table with only one row. I would like a table with rows for every line like that in the log.

What am i doing wrong ?

UPDATE :

It turns out that splunk views the whole .log file as one event. All the lines in the file are viewed together, instead of separately.

Something is off about uploading the log file to splunk, or about splunk interpreting the log file. (i said that the file should be viewed as sourcetype = log2metrics_keyvalue )

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like that with the correct separator:
`|eval rows=split(_raw,"\n")|stats count by rows|table rows`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your log file is not really of sourcetype log2metrics_keyvalue.  Create your own props.conf file stanza with line breaking settings that match your data.